# Axios post request returning 401

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, express

I'm trying to make a POST request to an API but I keep getting a 401 error.  I can make GET requests to the same API just fine with 200 status, so I'm wondering if my syntax is off somewhere.

The API I'm using is nocrm.io api and the POST request that I'm trying to make can be found here in their API reference: https://youdontneedacrm.com/api#create-a-lead

Here is my POST request from my server.js file

```
app.post('/crm/leads', (request, response) => {

    var baseurl = 'https://OURACCOUNT.nocrm.io/api/v2/'
    var apikey = 'API_KEY'
    var path = leads

        axios.post(baseurl + path, {
            params: {
                title: "Testing",
                description: "Business Name: Test Company",
                user_id: "someone@someemail.com",
                tags: ['TAG']
            },
            headers: {'X-API-KEY': apikey, content_type: "json", accept: "application/json"} 
        }).then(function(res){
            console.log("Good");
            response.send(res);
        }).catch(function(error){
            console.log("Error: " + error);
        })
}
```

This is my request within my client.js file

```
        $.post('/crm/leads').then(response => {
            console.log(response);
        }).catch(error => {
            console.log("Error: " + error);
        })
```

The error that I get back from this is: *Error: Request failed with 401 status*

Here is an example of a GET request that works just fine in server.js file

```
app.get('/crm/fields', (request, response) => {

    var baseurl = 'https://OURACCOUNT.nocrm.io/api/v2/'
    var apikey = 'API_KEY'
    var path = fields;

        axios.get(baseurl + path, {
            headers: {'X-API-KEY': apikey, content_type: "json", accept: "application/json"},
            params: {'type': "lead"}
        }).then(function(res){
            response.send(res.data);  // send data to client 
        }).catch(function(error){
            console.log("Error: " + error);
        })
}
```

This is the call to the GET request within my client.js file

```
$.get('/crm/fields').then(response => {
            console.log(response);
        }).catch(error => {
            console.log("Error: " + error);
        })
```

Any help or suggestions would be appreciated, thank you!

**[EDIT]**
I found out the problem.  My answer is below.

Comment: `Content-Type: application/json`?  the value `json` might not work for the server.

Comment: @DavinTryon this is the required header for the API call, which means that's what their server will be expecting.

Comment: In the curl command they show as an example, the content-type is `application/json`.  Where do you see it as `json`?

Comment: @DavinTryon  take a look at their ruby example.

Comment: I'm pretty sure that ruby `:json` expands to the value `application/json`.  Did you at least try it?

Comment: @DavinTryon I will try and let you know.

Comment: @DavinTryon still fails with 401

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution to my question while looking at the request logs from the API support.  The issue which wasn't clear to me at first, is that I have the headers within the parameters.

The request should look like this instead:

```
app.post('/crm/leads', (request, response) =>{
    var baseurl = 'https://OURACCOUNT.nocrm.io/api/v2/'
    var apikey = 'API_KEY'
    var path = leads

    var params = {
        title: "Testing",
        description: "Business Name: Test Company",
        user_id: "someone@someemail.com",
        tags: ["TAG"]
    }

     axios.post(baseurl + path,
            params
        ,{
            headers: {'X-API-KEY': apikey, content_type: "json", accept: 
        "application/json"} 
        }).then(function(res){
            console.log("Good");
            response.send(res);
        }).catch(function(error){
            console.log("Error: " + error);
        })
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can create a general requester to reduce redundancy

```
function doRequest(method: string, url: string, params?: Object, data?: Object){
    var headers ...;
    return axios({
      method: method,
      baseUrl: 'getfromconfig'
      url: url,
      data: data,
      params: params
    });
}
```

where data: to post, params: queryparams, method: GET/POST/PUT...
the headers can be inited inplace or pass as params. It's reusable in every file.

Comment: I didn't recognized your code, but I didnt know what version you use. I'd changed my answer to show a general way how I use to create requests. Maybe you can use it in your codebase as well.

Comment: Thanks for the input.  I put up an answer below yours to show how I got it to work.  It was a simple error that I completely look right passed.